# Movable stall along roads

Tags: word-usage, food

What do we call the movable food stalls set up on roadsides  more common in India? I usually refer to them as a cart or a food-stall.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link or a picture to describe what you mean?  If it's on *wheels* we'd probably call it a **food cart** or possibly a **food truck**.

Without wheels it would be a **food stand**, or possibly a **food stall**, depending on how they are organized.